# php string comparison considering spaces in between

Tags: php

in php i need to compare 2 strings.

```
str1="this is             a       string"
```

```
str2=" this is a string  "
```

I want to consider str1 and str2 to be the same string.

The way I can think is:

trim the strings first. extract the words of each string first, compare the words and then get the result.

Any better way i.e. bulit-in function or something else to make the comparison?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just use [`preg_replace()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) and [`trim()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php). The following:

```
<?php
$str1 = "this is             a       string";
$str2 = " this is a string  ";
$str1 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($str1));
$str2 = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', trim($str2));
var_dump($str1, $str2);
```

will output two identical strings:

```
string(16) "this is a string"
string(16) "this is a string"
```

See [this codepad](http://codepad.org/yOeVTO1B) as a proof.

Comment: Thanks, I missed that - the `"'\s+'"` string can be replaced by eg. `'/\s+/'` or `'<\s+>'` if you wish.

Comment: @MarcB: I changed delimiter from `'` to `/` so you can upvote now ;)

Answer (score 2):

What's wrong with `$str = preg_replace("/ +/"," ",$str);`? Just collapse multiple spaces into one...

Also, please start accepting answers on your older questions.

Comment: Wouldn't handle the extra space before/after the main string in str2. You'd need to `trim()` both strings as well.